# Counting Column Rows using return JSON and Linq on google charts

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, linq

Hi I am currently working on a project using asp.net MVC 5, I have come across an issue with the query where I cannot seem to count the all my rows and group them into a their related catagories

My SQL Statement Looks like this and it returns a count of orders which is grouped by the status.

```
SELECT COUNT(OrderID) as 'Orders' ,order_status FROM [ORDER]
group by order_status;
```

I'm looking to populate my Chart by using JSON currently in my controller I have the return Json

```
  public ActionResult GetChart()
    {
       var orders = db.Order.GroupBy(i => i.order_status).Select(i => new { Amount = i.Sum(b => b.OrderID), Name = i.Key }).OrderBy(i => i.Amount).Count();
        return Json(orders, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The chart draws well although there are no bars which are being displayed on the chart. Please help me out
Thanks in advance .

*I am still a beginner at this please bear in mind

Answer (score 0):

You have a call to `Count()` at the end of your query, which simply returns the number of elements in the IEnumerable. The type of your orders is actually `int` right now. If you remove the call, you will return the actual data, not just the amount of elements.

```
var orders = db.Order.GroupBy(i => i.order_status).Select(i => new { Amount = i.Sum(b => b.OrderID), Name = i.Key }).OrderBy(i => i.Amount);
```

The count of the orderIds is done in the `Sum` call, no need to count again.